# Prevent wxPython from swallowing context manager exits on SIGINT

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, sigint, contextmanager

It seems wxPython is intercepting any SIGINT in a way that prevents context manager `__exit__` calls from happening. Is there any way to fix this behavior?

Here is a small test program that demonstrates the issue:

```
import wx
import time

class Printer(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, x, y, z):
        print('### Context manager called!')

with Printer() as p:
    app = wx.App()
    frame = wx.Frame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
    #time.sleep(1000)
```

If you run it like this and press Ctrl+C, no output is generated. If you change the wx code to the sleep statement and press Ctrl+C, the context manager does what it is expected to do.

Comment: What happens if you close the Frame instead of pressing ctrl+c?  In most situations a GUI application won't remain active at the console when you launch it, so you'd never use ctrl+c to close it.

Comment: If I close the frame everything works correctly. On SIGINT even the wx handlers aren't called.

Comment: By default wxPython installs a default SIGINT handler. There's a comment that explains why: "This fixes a problem where if Ctrl-C is pressed in the console that started this app then it will not appear to do anything, (not even send KeyboardInterrupt???)  but will later segfault on exit.  By setting the default handler then the app will exit, as expected (depending on platform.)". You can disable it with `app = wx.App(clearSigInt=False)`, but then Ctrl-C will do nothing until you try to exit the app. See: http://osdir.com/ml/python.wxpython/2004-08/msg00148.html

Comment: I've seen that flag. Unfortunately, I still wasn't able to install a custom signal handler with the signal or atexit modules. They weren't called on SIGINT. I would really be great if there was a possibility to include custom cleanup code in the wx SIGINT reaction.